# Accepted answer with discussion that explains the problem vs workaround that solves the problem

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

My question refers specifically to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1299889/3482428

The comments explain why this answer is incorrect, and the answerer admited so and edited his answer adding a

> See the comments below - the following is not a correct explanation

The answerer's efforts are very valuable and the discussion that ensued in its comments is very important and relevant to the question, giving a very good explanation as to why this happens, but not really presenting a solution.

While I believe the discussion in this answer is actually the most important thing, as it deeply explains the problem, there is another answer that doesn't explain the issue but does provide a workaround which (I  believe) solves it, with good format and a code example.

Which answer should be marked as the correct answer? The one with the elightening discussion which leads to understanding the problem, or the one with the workaround (which is the correct way of solving the problem, as is understood from the previously mentioned discussion) and the code snippet?

Comment: The answer that solved your problem. If you really feel inclined to accept the former answer, tell the answerer to add the info in the comments to the answer. Wait for a reasonable time, and then accept.

Comment: That's what I would do, but it's not my question. Forgot to add that bit. Still thanks, I also wanted to know what to do if I was the asker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, the competing answer is better than the accepted answer. The right thing to do is to upvote the answer.

You are not the OP, and I am pretty sure there is a reason why the answer is still accepted. Sometimes, the OP just forgets to change the accept or still thinks that the accepted answer still deserves the accept.

You said that the accepted answer does not present a solution. That is incorrect as he has the bottom lines as the newer, more correct solution to the OP's answer, thus making the answer eligible for the accept. And the net votes on the accepted answer also tells you why the answer was accepted.

Comment: Well said; I can imagine why some people think accepting is a big deal; but after hanging here for a while, I've known good enough to ignore it.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for your answer!